# How to set timeout in C#

Tags: c#, thread-sleep

I would like to ask how to do it in my console application in C# to program must wait 3 seconds. For example, the program displays the line `Console.WriteLine("Hello!");` the program then wait 3 seconds and then writes the next line: `Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my program.");`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait one second in running program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458118/wait-one-second-in-running-program)

Comment: Please check out https://www.google.com/search?q=cgoogle&ie=&oe=#q=cgoogle+c-sharp+delay+program+execution and be sure to search for solutions both in Google and in SO before posting a new question - many times the answer is right there waiting for you!

Comment: You use the term "set timeout"... is your background in Javascript, are you asking for a C# equivalent of Javascripts `setTimeout` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my program.");
```