# c++ Run every 10 minute

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want this program run every start(call) 10min.

But I did not find a solution how-to call(start) Program every 10 minutes, on c++ code (man.exe).
I would like to use the code in visual studio 2013

```
 int runevery() {
        system("start man.exe");
        return true;
    }
```

Call:

```
#ifdef MAN_RUN
    runevery();
#endif
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait one second in running program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458118/wait-one-second-in-running-program)

Comment: Why not just schedule it to run using Windows Control Panel Task scheduler?

Comment: The program (man.exe) runs in the background on multiple computers. It would not be a lucky solution..:(

Answer (score 1):

You can create another thread that executes that function periodically until stopped. Example:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <condition_variable>

class PeriodicAction {
    std::mutex m_;
    std::condition_variable c_;
    bool stop_ = false;
    std::function<void()> const f_;
    std::chrono::seconds const initial_delay_;
    std::chrono::seconds const delay_;
    std::thread thread_;

    bool wait(std::chrono::seconds delay) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_);
        c_.wait_for(lock, delay, [this]() { return stop_; });
        return !stop_;
    }

    void thread_fn() {
        for(auto delay = initial_delay_; this->wait(delay); delay = delay_)
            f_();
    }

public:
    PeriodicAction(std::chrono::seconds initial_delay,
                   std::chrono::seconds delay,
                   std::function<void()> f)
        : f_(move(f))
        , initial_delay_(initial_delay)
        , delay_(delay)
        , thread_(&PeriodicAction::thread_fn, this)
    {}

    ~PeriodicAction() {
        this->stop();
        thread_.join();
    }

    void stop() {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_);
            stop_ = true;
        }
        c_.notify_one();
    }
};

char const* now_c_str() {
    auto time_t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    return std::ctime(&time_t);
}

int main(int ac, char**) {
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

    // Print current time for the next 5 seconds and then terminate.
    PeriodicAction a(0s, 1s, []() { std::cout << now_c_str(); });
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
}
```

Applying to your case:

```
PeriodicAction a(0s, 600s, [](){ system("start man.exe"); });
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But not working...Error 2 error C2039: 'chrono_literals' : is not a member of 'std' (Visual Studio)

Comment: @Returnerpeople Instead of suffixes like `0s` you can use the longer syntax `std::chrono::seconds(0)`.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is thiis:
Error 3 error C2039: 'chrono_literals' : is not a member of 'std'

Comment: @Returnerpeople Remove that line with `using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;` and use the longer syntax `std::chrono::seconds(0)`.

Comment: @Returnerpeople I do not have access to visual studio 2013 to try it out, I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good idea, but it's easy to achieve like this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    while (true)
        {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::minutes(10));
        system("man.exe");
        }
}
```

I still think as per my earlier comment that a scheduled task on Windows would be better behaved and easier configurable.

Comment: Yes, thank you for reply! But the program original program not starting, and the man.exe not starting.