# WebView2 returns wrong height with javascript, when navigation completed

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webview2

I'm getting the height of WebView2 content by javascript, when navigation is completed...

```
string script = "setTimeout(wait, 10); function wait() {}; var height = document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight.toString(); console.log('Height = ' + height); eval(height);";  
var heightString = await webView.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);  
  
if (int.TryParse(heightString, out int height))  
    {  
      
        int h = (int)((float)height);  
        int w = ScreenFramework.getPanelContentWidthWithPadding();  
        if(position == POSITION_MENU)  
        {  
            w = ApplicationFramework.MENU_WIDTH - ApplicationFramework.PADDING;  
        }  
      
        webView.MinimumSize = new Size(w, 0);  
        webView.MaximumSize = new Size(w, h + 2 * ApplicationFramework.MARGIN);  
        webView.Size = new Size(w, h + 2 * ApplicationFramework.MARGIN);  
}
```

This functionality returns wrong height of content, when page is little longer.
I have to call it twice, to get right value.
Is there any problem, with this control?
Or what am i doing wrong?

I'm expecting to get right value. The value returned is sometimes smaller then actual height of contet. I tried to call this function twice to get right value.

EDIT

I found some approch, here>

```
string script = "window.chrome.webview.postMessage(\"ready\");";
WebView.NavigationCompleted += (sender, e) => { WebView.ExecuteScriptAsync(script); WebView.WebMessageReceived += readyReceived; };
```

then

```
public void readyReceived(object sender, CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string t = e.TryGetWebMessageAsString();
        if (t == "ready")
        {
            setWebViewHeight(WebView, Position);
            WebView.Visible = true;
        }
    } catch { }

}
```

Now it seems to work, must test it hardly ;)

Comment: The java code is probably not completing.  Java continues to run after navigation is completed.

Comment: Sure it is, problem is that NavigationComplete seems to be called sooner, then document is fully loaded ;)

Comment: As I said, Java code is still running after NavigationComplete event occurs.  Usually to resolve this type issue I wait for an object in the Java code to change from null to a real value.  The object is different for every webpage.  Then I know when java completes and then get all the other values.

Comment: Yes, i edited question, added new approach, that seems to work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your code below

```
string script = "setTimeout(wait, 10); function wait() {}; var height = document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight.toString(); console.log('Height = ' + height); eval(height);";
```

calls `setTimeout` and tells the event loop that in 10 milliseconds `wait` is to be executed, then proceeds computing your height measurements without waiting. If you want to wait for 10 milliseconds, then move your height measurement into wait along with your other Javascript code that relies upon it.

EDIT

Let me illustrate how settimeout works.

```js
setTimeout(wait, 3000);

function wait() {
    console.log("inside wait");
}

console.log("outside wait");
```

EDIT2

`eval` inside timeout

```js
setTimeout(wait, 10);
function wait() {
    var height = document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight.toString();
    console.log('Height = ' + height); eval(height);
}
```

```css
#content {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

But I advise anyone to avoid using `eval` whenever possible, because it's bad practice.

Comment: I want to wait 10ms, because when i access height property directly, it returns wrong value. Spent almost day, to solve this "issue" and ended up with calling this method twice to get right value ;)

Comment: @Dzio but you are not waiting 10 milliseconds to compute the height. You are scheduling to run `wait`, an empty function after 10 milliseconds, but then your height is being calculated.

Comment: @Dzio I edited my answer to illustrate how `setTimeout` works. As you can see, I schedule `wait` to be executed after 3 seconds. When that's done, it will type `inside wait` in the console. Afterwards I log `outside wait`. What you will see when testing is that `outside wait` is typed instantly. Because it is being executed synchronously. And for the same reason your height is being computed prematurely. After 3 seconds, `inside wait` appears as well. You want your height computation to be done **inside** the `wait` function, not outside of it.

Comment: Ah, ok, i understand, but there i cannot use eval, which is needed for this function ;)

Comment: @Dzio why not ?

Comment: @Dzio I have made a further edit to my answer that demonstrates that `eval` works inside `setTimeout`. But let's not use it, eval is bad practice.

Comment: Don't know why, it isn't working this way, like nothing is returned back to c# ;)

Comment: To eval, hmm, i saw this code at some web page, looks like it works that way ;)

Comment: @Dzio can you wait for page finished and then run the height getter? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url

Comment: This is android example, i am doing c# ;)

Comment: @Dzio the idea is the same. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458118/wait-one-second-in-running-program

Comment: Idea is good, but there are not those functions in c# like in java ;)

Comment: @Dzio have you tried `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);`?

Comment: Yes, i tried ;) No change ;)

Comment: @Dzio are you using threads?

Comment: Nope, i am not ;)

Comment: @Dzio then the entire process freezes while it's sleeping. It would be great if you had a thread for loading the resource and another one to sleep and then run your script. Then while the second thread sleeps, the first finishes loading, so when the second thread runs your script, it's ready to do so.

Comment: Ok, i'll try ;)